# Setting width and height using jQuery isotope plugin

Tags: jquery, height, width, jquery-isotope

I'm using the jQuery Isotope plugin, and although I have it working, I can't seem to get it to recognise any margins.

I can see in Firebug that the margins are being applied, but the items are just overlapping the margin (I think becasuse isotope uses absolute positioning).

I had the width working briefly by using the following:

```
masonry : {
columnWidth : 172
          }
```

but I couldn't figure out how to get the height working (I tried rowHeight with masonry, and masonryHorizontal).

How do I tell isotope what widths, and heights to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code:

```
$(window).load() instead of $(document).ready()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that Isotope is doing its thing before the images are loaded.
Use this code:

```
var $container = $('#container');

$container.imagesLoaded(function() {
  $container.isotope({
    // options...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar (if not the same) problem; I had no vertical spacing between my items. Make sure you're including the following CSS properties on your tiled elements:

```
.element {
  width: 110px; /*your columnWidth minus 10px */
  height: 110px; /*same as width, for a square grid system*/
  margin: 5px; /*5px here will result in 10px of vertical spacing between tiles*/
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

Hope this helps.